# Bar chart design

Tags: php, html

I have try to create the bar chart for displaying my data but there is problem occurred.

Here's the code:

```
<?php 

 $gpa11=$_REQUEST['gpa11'];
 $gpa12=$_REQUEST['gpa12'];

 $gpa21=$_REQUEST['gpa21'];
 $gpa22=$_REQUEST['gpa22'];

 $gpa31=$_REQUEST['gpa31'];
 $gpa32=$_REQUEST['gpa32'];

 $gpa41=$_REQUEST['gpa41'];
 $gpa42=$_REQUEST['gpa42'];

 $gpa51=$_REQUEST['gpa51'];
 $gpa52=$_REQUEST['gpa52'];

?>

<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php');

$data1y=array($gpa11,$gpa21,$gpa31,$gpa41, $gpa51);
$data2y=array($gpa12,$gpa22,$gpa32,$gpa42, $gpa52);



// Create the graph. These two calls are always required
$graph = new Graph(350,200,'auto');
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

$theme_class=new UniversalTheme;
$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);

$graph->yaxis->SetTickPositions(array(0,30,60,90,120,150), array(15,45,75,105,135));
$graph->SetBox(false);

$graph->ygrid->SetFill(false);
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('Year 1','Year 2','Year 3','Year 4','Year 5'));
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);

// Create the bar plots
$b1plot = new BarPlot($data1y);
$b2plot = new BarPlot($data2y);

// Create the grouped bar plot
$gbplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($b1plot,$b2plot));
// ...and add it to the graPH
$graph->Add($gbplot);


$b1plot->SetColor("white");
$b1plot->SetFillColor("#cc1111");

$b2plot->SetColor("white");
$b2plot->SetFillColor("#11cccc");

$graph->title->Set("GPA Performance Graph");

// Display the graph
$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

When I trying to display my bar chart, it show "JpGraph Error: 25067 Your manually specified scale and ticks is not correct. The scale seems to be too small to hold any of the specified tick marks." Please advice what I have to do to correct this.

Comment: hello I shw your code looks very difficult but you can find the graph with solution here:
http://www.terrill.ca/design/vertical_bar_graphs/

Comment: denny, Thanks for the reply. I get my problem solved.

Comment: you may want to comment/answer your question so other can benefit from it.

Comment: How did you fix this problem? Could you share the solution?